# Spring @Component creation order

Tags: java, spring, components

I tried to find answer on the question above, but I didn't.
So, What is Spring @Component creation order?
For example: We have

```
@Component
public class Foo extends SecondClass {
   private SomeType someField;

   @Autowired
   public Foo(SomeType someField){
    super(someField);
   }
}

public class SecondClass implement ISomething {
  //code and @override methods...
  @PostConstruct 
  public void method(ISomething i) {
    //Actions with i
  }
}
```

What will be creation order? What will be created first, parent or child in this particular case? Thanks..

Comment: In this case you have only one Bean created for class `Foo` which has a super class `SecondClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity sake, ignore the beans that will be created in the background as part of a Spring application.

Since you have `@Component` on class `Foo` alone, single Spring bean will be created. It does not matter the creation order because there is only one bean being created here since you do not have `@Component` on any other class. You will have to manually instantiate `SecondClass` by yourself if you want to make use of it.

Regarding inheritance question, Spring does not get involved with that. It will be taken care of by Java itself.

edit:

`@PostConstruct` will be ignored because `SecondClass` is not a Spring bean. But since we are using `super`, it will be called This is a complete program that tests creation order of bean.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestProgram implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestProgram.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo extends SecondClass {
        @Override
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("Printing Foo class");
            //new change
            super.method(); 
        }
    }

    public static class SecondClass implements Cloneable {
        //Since you are calling this method via super in Foo class, you don't need 
        //this annotation as it is being ignored anyway since this class is not a 
        //bean.
        @PostConstruct
        public void method() {
          System.out.println("Printing Second Class");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Spring application is up.");
    }
}
```

It will print both now as we are using super call to invoke `SecondClass` method.

> Printing Foo class
>
> Printing Second Class

You don't need @PostConstruct in `SecondClass` as it is not a Spring bean and that's why it was getting ignored without `super` call.

Play around by removing/adding annotations and you will get it.

Comment: Thanks, understand. I've little edited my question. So if I have only Foo bean, why  @PostConstruct method is executed?

Comment: Thanks, understood. We have to add @Component, to make it works

Comment: Okay, my fail, i've edited my question. Does constructor with super() get the @PostConstruct method done?

Answer (score 1):

The @Order annotation defines the sorting order of an annotated component or bean.It has an optional value argument which determines the order of the component.So,you can arrange your bean according to it's priority.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful information, but I already have  working code shown above, so I just want to understand how it works.

Comment: If class Foo is extends SecondClass so,it means you have to intialize class-bean SecondClass before Foo.so,by using @DependsOn(class name) you can intialize SecondClass before the Foo class